# Vue.JS's router has "#" even with history mode enabled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I tried to remove # in URL of my VueJS webapp, but even with

```
const router = createRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes
})
```

# still appear.
I'm pretty sure it's due to the createWebHashHistory function, but I can't remove it, or else, UI doesn't display.

So i tried another thing :

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: true,
    routes
})
```

but ui doesn't even display here.

The Vue.JS's official documentation doesn't help me on that point, could anyone help me there ?

Comment: You see the `#` because you've set the mode to hash with `history: createWebHashHistory()`. For history mode, use `history: createWebHistory()` instead. And remove `mode` since that's no longer used in Vue Router 4.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

So it is either `history: createWebHashHistory(),` or the `createRouter`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import About from "../views/About.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    component: About,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```